# A tesselation where four parallel rectangles meet at each vertex

Tags: rectangles, tiling, tessellations

If we tile the plane with parallel rectangles that are translated copy of the same rectangle, then each point is either inside a tile, or on a segment common to two adjacent tiles, or a corner common to four tiles (but there is no point common to exactly three tiles).

Are there other tilings of the plane with the same property, using parallel rectangles of *different* sizes?

Comment: Take three parallel lines the first two a distance $a$ apart, the second two a distance $b$ apart. Now place $a\times d$ rectangles between the first two and $b\times d$ rectangles between the second two. That can obviously be extended to cover the plane.

Comment: @almagest OK, th anks. Is this the most general type of tiling with this property?

Comment: No. For example, you could alternate $a\times d_1$ with $a\times d_2$ (provided you alternate $b\times d_1$ with $b\times d_2$ to match).